# Property change caused by route change won't update view - *ngIf

Tags: javascript, html, angular

So I have a kind of custom select bar with `products-header__select` expanding the list on click. To do so I created the property `expanded` which is supposed to describe its current state. With `*ngIf` I either display it or not.

It works fine clicking the `products-header__select`. But a click on one of the expanded list's items changes the route, the path and some other element changes, but the `products-header__select` remains visible.

All good, but I want to collapse the list on route change - my approach was to listen to router events and then run `expanded = false` when the navigation has ended. - But somehow the view won't update and the list remains expanded, even though running `console.log(this.expanded)` inside of the router event returns `false`. Why won't it update then?

View:

```
<div class="products-header__select" (click)="expanded = !expanded">
  <ul>
    <li class="basic-text__small custom-select">{{mobileCategories ? (mobileCategories[0].name | transformAllProducts) : ''}}</li>
    <div class="select-options" *ngIf="expanded">
      <li class="basic-text__small" *ngFor="let category of mobileCategories.slice(1, mobileCategories.length); let i = index" routerLink="/products/{{category.name.toLowerCase()}}">
        {{category?.name | transformAllProducts}}
      </li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {NavigationEnd, Router, RouterEvent} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-products-header',
  templateUrl: './products-header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products-header.component.scss']
})
export class ProductsHeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  expanded = false;
  url: string;

  $categories;
  @Input() set categories(value) {
    if (value) {
      this.$categories = value;
      this.createArrayForMobile();
      this.getActiveRoute();
    }
  }

  mobileCategories: any[];

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.expanded = false;
        this.url = event.url;
        this.getActiveRoute();
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  getActiveRoute() {
    if (!this.mobileCategories) { return; }
    const decodedUrl = decodeURI(this.url);
    const index = this.mobileCategories.findIndex(item => decodedUrl.includes(item.name.toLowerCase()));
    const obj = this.mobileCategories[index];
    this.mobileCategories.splice(index, 1);
    this.mobileCategories.unshift(obj);
  }

  createArrayForMobile() {
    this.mobileCategories = [...this.$categories, {name: 'all'}];
  }


}
```

That's how I use it:

```
<app-products-header [categories]="categories"></app-products-header>
```

Comment: Are you using code outside of angular?  Maybe your leaving ngZone

Comment: Are you using default change detection for the component or onPush?

Comment: it will be easier to set `expanded = false` on (click) on <li>

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz demo reproducing the issue?

Comment: @Nabel No, nothing that I know of.

Comment: @NikhilWalvekar Default, at least I haven't changed something on purpose.

Comment: @Gendy `expanded = !expanded` works fine on click - it solely isn't working on route change.

Comment: @David Somehow it's working on stackblitz no matter what I do, hence I updated the post with the whole component - can't explain why it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the answer but things I would try would be:

1. Try subscribing to the router events in `ngOnInit() {}` rather than the constructor.
2. Try specifically calling change detection.

   ```
   constructor(private router: Router, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
   router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
     if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
       this.expanded = false;
       this.url = event.url;
       this.getActiveRoute();
       this.cdr.detectChanges();
     }
   });}
   ```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately didn't work though - after hours of trying I found a solution: I had to wrap the router's code with a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Had to wrap the router event's code with a timeout:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
  router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.expanded = false;
        this.url = event.url;
        this.getActiveRoute();
      });
    }
  });
}
```